# Landau-Ramanujan constant calculation python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate the L-R constat K with this algorithm:

```
def betaD(x):
    return ((4**(-x))*(zeta(x,1/4)-zeta(x,3/4)))

K = 1

lista = np.arange(1,9,1,dtype=float)

for n in lista:
    K = K * (((1-(1/((2)**(2**n))))*(zeta(2**n)/betaD(2**n)))**(1/(2**(n+1))))
    print(K)
    
K = K*(1/np.sqrt(2))
```

(zeta is from scipy.special)

As you can see I can only reach 9 iteration, otherwise K becomes = 0 and I get:

```
/home/martina/pymartina/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  if __name__ == '__main__':
/home/martina/pymartina/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

Anyone can help? I'd like to be able to get more iterations and precision. Thanks

Comment: Any debugging done yet? What where your findings?

Answer (score 0):

When `n<10`, it is possible to calculate `betaD(2**n)`.
When `n>10`, `zeta(2**n,1/4)` is infinite, so there is an error in `betaD(2**n)`.

The `decimal` library can handle the size of your data : https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: Thank you! I was not able to figure out where the problem was. Now I will try to use decimal library.